# Remove everything after nth occurrence of character, using sed

Tags: bash, sed

If you create a file test.txt with these 2 lines, then grep | cut the second line, like this:

```
echo "ExportFormatIdx=14
ExportFormatNames=unquoted, quoted, more, CSVmore, ExtU, Extended, HTML, XML, Details, TOC, Custom, Primary, Core, bash, removethis" > test.txt
grep ExportFormatNames test.txt | cut -f1-14 -d','
```

The output is:

```
ExportFormatNames=unquoted, quoted, more, CSVmore, ExtU, Extended, HTML, XML, Details, TOC, Custom, Primary, Core, bash
```

The result: starting with the 14th comma, everything is correctly removed from that line. In this case:

*, removethis*

Is it possible to do the same approach (replace everything following, and including, the nth comma), but as an in-place line change, using sed?

If you do:

```
grepresult="$(grep ExportFormatNames test.txt | cut -f1-14 -d',')"; echo "grep result is $grepresult";sed -i '/ExportFormatNames/c\"$grepresult"' test.txt
```

The result of

```
cat test.txt
```

is:

```
ExportFormatIdx=14
"$grepresult"
```

Will sed only accept string literals? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: You need to use double quotes in order for variable expansion to take place.

Comment: Tried it in double quotes like this: sed -i "/ExportFormatNames/c\$grepresult" test.txt, which did not work, but this one did: sed -i '/ExportFormatNames/c\'"$grepresult" test.txt - thanks!